# How to use Azure storage blob services

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need your help as I am new to this field. I want to use Azure storage blob service to upload images, list and download, but I am facing some problems.

I have imported a project from [this repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-java-quickstart), and as soon as I import I am getting errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/NUTRIP-DEVLP1/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar' in project 'blobAzureApp' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    blobAzureApp        Build path  Build Path Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    blobAzureApp        Unknown Java Problem
```

Should I run this as a normal Java application or a Maven project? If Maven, how do I run it?

Comment: thank you for the response but this not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using official [java sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) in your maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

***sample upload code:***

```
static void uploadFile(BlockBlobURL blob, File sourceFile) throws IOException {

    FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath());

    // Uploading a file to the blobURL using the high-level methods available in TransferManager class
    // Alternatively call the Upload/StageBlock low-level methods from BlockBlobURL type
    TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blob, 8*1024*1024, null)
        .subscribe(response-> {
            System.out.println("Completed upload request.");
            System.out.println(response.response().statusCode());
        });
}
```

***sample list code:***

```
static void listBlobs(ContainerURL containerURL) {
    // Each ContainerURL.listBlobsFlatSegment call return up to maxResults (maxResults=10 passed into ListBlobOptions below).
    // To list all Blobs, we are creating a helper static method called listAllBlobs, 
    // and calling it after the initial listBlobsFlatSegment call
    ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions(null, null, 10);

    containerURL.listBlobsFlatSegment(null, options)
        .flatMap(containersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse -> 
            listAllBlobs(containerURL, containersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse))    
                .subscribe(response-> {
                    System.out.println("Completed list blobs request.");
                    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
                });
}

private static Single <ContainersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse> listAllBlobs(ContainerURL url, ContainersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse response) {                
    // Process the blobs returned in this result segment (if the segment is empty, blobs() will be null.
    if (response.body().blobs() != null) {
        for (Blob b : response.body().blobs().blob()) {
            String output = "Blob name: " + b.name();
            if (b.snapshot() != null) {
                output += ", Snapshot: " + b.snapshot();
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("There are no more blobs to list off.");
    }

    // If there is not another segment, return this response as the final response.
    if (response.body().nextMarker() == null) {
        return Single.just(response);
    } else {
        /*
        IMPORTANT: ListBlobsFlatSegment returns the start of the next segment; you MUST use this to get the next
        segment (after processing the current result segment
        */

        String nextMarker = response.body().nextMarker();

        /*
        The presence of the marker indicates that there are more blobs to list, so we make another call to
        listBlobsFlatSegment and pass the result through this helper function.
        */

    return url.listBlobsFlatSegment(nextMarker, new ListBlobsOptions(null, null,1))
        .flatMap(containersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse ->
            listAllBlobs(url, containersListBlobFlatSegmentResponse));
    }
}
```

***sample download code:***

```
static void getBlob(BlockBlobURL blobURL, File sourceFile) {
    try {
        // Get the blob using the low-level download method in BlockBlobURL type
        // com.microsoft.rest.v2.util.FlowableUtil is a static class that contains helpers to work with Flowable
        blobURL.download(new BlobRange(0, Long.MAX_VALUE), null, false)
            .flatMapCompletable(response -> {
                AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths
                    .get(sourceFile.getPath()), StandardOpenOption.CREATE,  StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                        return FlowableUtil.writeFile(response.body(), channel);
            }).doOnComplete(()-> System.out.println("The blob was downloaded to " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()))
            // To call it synchronously add .blockingAwait()
            .subscribe();
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

More details, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-v10).Hope it helps you.

Comment: yes i have tried this also but i am not getting output

Comment: @sujatabhavi Even though you create a pure maven project?